# Think in the shadow. What does it mean? Is it an idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Ian sits in the dark, thinking in the shadows.

I've across the phrase above in a novel.

I don't understand the meaning.

Does "shadows" symply mean "shadows"?

Or  "thinking in the shadows" is an idiom?
Could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> Beverly thought she caught an odd look on Ian’s face in the shadows,
>   when they brought Bradley in. Something cold in his eyes that she
>   hadn’t seen before. It gave her a chill. She’s not sure—the expression
>   was so fleeting. She might have imagined it. [...] His wife[Beverly]
>   appears silently at his side, kneeling down by his chair, making him
>   jump. It’s almost as if she’s read his mind. “Henry,” she whispers,
>   her voice so low that he has to lean his ear down next to her lips to
>   hear what she wants to tell him. He can smell her breath. He wonders
>   if she can possibly know what he’s thinking. “I think I know who the
>   killer is.” He raises his head and looks at her frightened eyes,
>   gleaming in the dark. Ian doesn’t like the way Beverly’s been looking
>   at him. She’s gone over to her husband and is leaning close to him,
>   whispering something in his ear. That’s interesting, seeing as usually
>   she’s stayed a good distance away from her husband lately. He wonders
>   what she’s saying. Maybe something about him.
>   **Ian sits in the dark, thinking in the shadows**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence can be simplified to:

> Ian sits in the dark, thinking.

The addition of *in the shadows* is simply to set the mood poetically or descriptively.

It could also have been written as:

> Ian sits among the shadows, thinking.

Or, in different descriptive situations:

> Ian sits in the dark, thinking about his plight.
>   Ian sits in the dark, writing in chalk on the floor.

In other words, *thinking in the shadows* is not an idiom or a set expression. It's just being descriptive.

More than that, it's actually a stylistic reference back to the opening sentence of the paragraph:

> Beverly thought she caught an odd look on Ian’s face *in the shadows* . . . Ian sits in the dark, thinking *in the shadows*.